# Dynamic Charts In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

Is it possible to add a new series to a chart when adding a new column to a table?

For example, I have the following chart:

[image: Chart]

Pulling data from this table:

[image: Table]

If if I add a new column to the table, for example:

[image: New Data]

and this

[image: New Data]

Is there away to get a new series added to the chart?

Comment: In addition to Bandersnatch's automated method, you can manually add a series via accessing the chart's data definition.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this question.  I've wanted to be able to do this in a graph myself, and you made me go find out how to do it.  :-)

The key is to create a named Excel table for your data table.  Then, when you add data to the table, it is automatically added to your graph.

Since you already have a data table, you can easily convert it into a named table by selecting the data (including headers) and typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-T.

The only downside to this is Excel will pick some awful, ugly, automatic format for your table, but you can fix that with a little searching through all the possible choices.

Now, you can click in the table and use the Insert menu on the Tables tab to insert a new column.  As soon as you paste in your new data, it will appear as a new series on your graph.

[image]

I'm sure the details of this will vary depending on your version of Excel, but I hope this helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Select the new column of data including the heading (=series name).
Copy.
Select the chart.
Paste.

Behaves nicely if ranges are the same length. If not, and depending on chart type, you may get odd results. But generally this "just works".