# Can I add additional data to embedded excel graph in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a simple graph with 2 lines embeded in PowerPoint. If I want to add new data like a new month, I can just add these in Excel.

However I now would like to add a new line.  But it seems not possible.  When in the Excel I add a new line between the 2 existing columns, there is no new line created in my graph.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the issue (just upload it to e.g. imgur and post the link in your question)? Does it work if you do it in a pure Excel file, just have the issue with Excel embedded in power point?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to convert your data table into a named Excel table. See [this recent answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1294996/dynamic-charts-in-excel/1295073#1295073) to a similar question.

That will make the new data appear in your Excel chart. Then, to have it appear in your PowerPoint presentation, you will have to [Refresh Data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-linked-excel-chart-in-powerpoint-692497a5-c7de-4486-a435-5af1eff02821) in PowerPoint.

Comment: Or select the data you want to include and give the range a name.  Then link the named range rather than to a specific range of cells.  As you insert new rows into the range, the named range will include them.